# How do you detect if a remote website uses flash?

Tags: php, flash, curl, header

I am trying to write a tool that detects if a remote website uses flash using php. So far I have written a script that detects if embed or objects exist which give an indicator that there is a possibility of it being installed but some sites encrypt their code so renders this function useless.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$flashTotalCount    = 0;
function file_get_contents_curl($url){

        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);    
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);    
        return $data;
    }

    $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html); 

foreach($html->find('embed') as $pageEmbed){
$flashTotalCount++;
}

foreach($html->find('object') as $pageObject){
$flashTotalCount++;
}

if($flashTotalCount == 0){  
echo "NO FLASH";    
}   
else{   
echo "FLASH";
}
```

Would anyone one know of a way to check to see if a website uses flash or if possible get header information that flash is being used etc.

Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: Does it crash or leak memory? It uses Flash... but seriously look for the `object` element and look to see whether the extension is `.swf` etc would probably work out ok.

Comment: You could look at the javascript src files for the swfobject library to get a pretty good detection rate but of course you can never detect it for sure, any site can just use custom js code hidden in some minified javascript file to embed flash dynamically

Comment: you need to check the object sizes as you could get an add made in flash or a navigation menu, while the site is not using flash to display its content

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, flash can be loaded by javascript. So you should execute the web page. For this purposes you'll have to use tool like this: 
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#the-waitfor-commands-in-ajax-applications

I don't think that it is usable from php.